# How to Open a PDF file returned by hitting a URL and simply viewing it on click of a button

Tags: android

heyy people i am new to android plzz do help. i am making an android app where i want want if a person wants to see a PDF file can just open the app click the button and open and view the PDF file.

what i have actually done is created a JSP which is connected to a database. when i run the JSP it takes d report fills it with the data from the db n returns a PDF file

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/And_sample");
InputStream is=new FileInputStream(new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("android_report1.jasper")));
JasperPrint jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, null, connection);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp,getServletContext().getRealPath("android_report1.pdf"));

OutputStream os=response.getOutputStream();
JRExporter jre=new JRPdfExporter();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
jre.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,jp);
jre.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,os);
jre.exportReport();
```

now i want to show this PDF file returned in an app which hits the JSP URL and reads and displays the PDF report within my app or using the default PDF viewer in the emulator but i dnt know how to do it. i do not know how to read pdf files on click of a button and show it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can view pdf from app using webview.

Check this

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + yourpdfUrl);
```

There are also other libraries for viewing and editing pdf from app.